# Lack of knowledge to initializing viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Okay. So what I need to do is to initialize a `ViewModel` using a constructor. The problem is I can't create the constructor due lack of knowledge. I'm new to `MVVM` (or c# in general for that matter) and had to get some help to implement this code:

```
public class ViewModel
{
  private static ViewModel instance = new ViewModel();

  public static ViewModel Instance
  {
     get
     {
        return instance;
     }
  }
}
```

However, I fail to create a constructor to place this code.

```
DataContext = ViewModel.Instance
```

It is meant to go into two different pages to pass a value between `TextBoxes`.
I'm also confused as to whether I should put the `ViewModel` in both the main window and the page or in just one of the two.

So, anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

Follow this pattern:

This part is how your model classes should look like,
Even if you use entity framework to create your model they inherit INPC.. so all good.

```
public class Model_A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // list of properties...
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   // etc...
}
```

each view model is a subset of information to be viewed, so you can have many view models for the same model class, notice that in case your make the call to the parameter-less c-tor you get auto instance of a mock model to be used in the view model.

```
public class ViewModel_A1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Model_A instance;

  public ViewModel()
  {
     instance = new instance
     { //your mock value for the properties..
       FirstName = "Offer",
       LastName = "Somthing"
     };
  }

  public ViewModel(Model_A instance)
  { 
    this.instance = instance;
  }
}
```

And this is for your view, if you view in the ide designer you will have a mock view model to show.

```
public class View_For_ViewModelA1
{
  public View_For_ViewModel_A1()
  {
     //this is the generated constructor already implemented by the ide, just add to it:
     DataContext = new ViewModel_A1();

  }

  public View_For_ViewModel_A1(ViewModel_A1 vm)
  {
    DataContext = vm;
  }
}
```

XAML Side:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.View_For_ViewModel_A1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:ViewModel_A1, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
       <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In a more advanced scenario you would want to have a single view model class to relate to several model classes.. but you always should set a view to bind to a single view model.
if you need to kung-fu with your code - make sure you do that in your view model layer.
(i.e. creating a view-model that have several instances of different model types)

Note: This is not the complete pattern of mvvm.. in the complete pattern you can expose command which relate to methods in your model via your view-model and bind-able to your view as well.
Good luck :)

Comment: okay i just looked up "mock values for properties" but it seems these can vary widely. How do i find mine. What am i looking for?

Comment: mock values are something you decide to hard code or simulate to test your view model and view.. so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: well you anotated a part "{//your mock value for the properties..}" so i'm guessing by this you mean the text box I wish to bind?

Comment: something that keeps throwing me off is that i get the error INotifyPropertyChanged could not be found... am i not supposed to enter this in the main window?

Comment: I think you might have too much to cover, go to this link to learn more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I basically follow this pattern:

```
    public class ViewModelWrappers
    {
        static MemberViewModel _memberViewModel;
        public static MemberViewModel MemberViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                if (_memberViewModel == null)
                    _memberViewModel = new MemberViewModel(Application.Current.Resources["UserName"].ToString());

                return _memberViewModel;
            }
        }
...
}
```

To bind this to a page is:

```
DataContext = ViewModelWrappers.MemberViewModel;
```

And if I'm using more than 1 ViewModel on the page I just bind to the wrapper.

```
DataContext = ViewModelWrappers;
```

Comment: Okay I've filled this code in. I only get one error though "MemberViewModel is a property but is used like a type" it shows up for each of them. Know what i'm missing?

Comment: and if im not mistaken, DataContext is put in te same section as initialize component yes?

Comment: Two things have the same name, change the name of the property.  I bind in thee load event of the page. Something like this.Loaded += MyPage_Loaded;

Comment: okay so i generated a class for it and now it seems there's something else: Error 'Masca.MemberViewModel' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments :/ any clue to that? sorry to be such a bother

Comment: I pass in the UserName to the constructor. You would just remove that from your "new" statement.

Comment: I insert username.Text and i still get the same error... Sigh# there's a drop down option though to generate a user stub.  _memberViewModel = new         ViewModelWrappers(Application.Current.Resources[UserName.text].ToString()); thats what it looks like...

Comment: or should i put username.text in brackets because no error comes up when i do that.

Comment: If the constructor of your class doesn't take a parameter, then just remove the parameter when you call new.

Comment: don't pass a string into the constructor of your class if the constructor of your class doesn't take a string. So "new MyClass(UserName)" would be just "new MyClass()"

Comment: And its still not working, probably at my on incapability of knowing how to implement this... but that's okay. I think i've taken up enough of your time. Much gratitude JBrooks

Answer (score 0):

If you or anybody else, who's new to the MVVM, gets stuck here, for example at the "*INotifyPropertyChanged could not be found*". I recommend trying some example-MVVM's or tutorials.

**Some I found useful:**

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpGvqVtSYjs&index=1&list=PL356CA0B2C8E7548D